# RethinkDB with NodeJS: Open individual connections vs single static connection

Tags: node.js, architecture, rethinkdb

I am currently developing a real-time app with rethinkdb and node, and there are many different rethinkdb queries to run in different classes. So, my question is, does it make more sense to have a single rethinkdb connection which every query must open and close, or a single connection where every query is run, statically available?

From [this issue](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/3296) I deduce that parallelization is already an option, so this is a matter of what is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to have a pool of open connections to your RethinkDB server. For example rethinkdbdash (which I recommend you use) opens a pool of 50 connections that are available for your queries.